# Stuck on setting priorities

Tags: job-search, job-offer

Though it may sound more of asking for a personal advice but please try to take it as a professional one.

I am working as a Technical Consultant for 3 years now and I am well settled with my Job. I will be getting married in Jan'16. My Fiance is working in a reputed International Bank since last 2 years.

Now, that we both work in different locations, and her bank doesn't have a branch at my location, we started searching for a job for her at my location. Its been 3 months and due to lack of referrals and the long distance location she didn't got any opportunities for any interviews.

Last week on Friday, she finally got a call and her telephonic interview went well. But, again, there is no response from the HR about the next steps. She has a notice period of 3 months and will have to resign in October.

I don't want to put her job on risk as I respect her hard work and her passion about her work. How should I prepare myself for the next step? Should we call/email the HR for the response? Or should we wait for a few days more? Its too difficult to have patience in this kind of situation.

If anyone has faced this kind of circumstances, let me know how you were able to tackle it.

Update -

I forgot to add the things where I am stuck. The following are the cases/options I have in my plate -

1. I have an option of Work from Home. Which means, I can relocate to a place where she has got the location. But both of us are not comfortable with that location.
2. I am waiting for a call from an HR as well. If I get that, I can refer her as well.
3. She needs to quit her job, relocate to my place and then start looking for a new job. Which I think might not go well.

We have like a week or two to decide our next step. So, any suggestion, personal experiences, or a personal guidance will help.

I hope this makes the question a bit different from the already asked one.

Comment: @Philip - Thanks for the link. I have visited it earlier and found it helpful. Though, I have a bit more in my plate. That's why I created a new thread. Thanks again.

Comment: @BSC, what specifically about your question is different from the linked question that you think will change the answers given?

Comment: Sorry, still looks the same to me.  Someone had an interview, hasn't heard back (good or bad), and is wondering how to follow up, what the other question asked.  Voting to close.

Comment: You should stay entirely out of her process of getting a new job. It is  inappropriate for you to followup with HR. She is an adult and needs to handle her own life.

Comment: they're engaged to be married, that means they expect to share their lives (I assume), that seems a good enough reason to me for him to have an input into her decisions and vice versa

Comment: @Kilisi Thanks. That's what I am looking forward to. Its not about just waiting for the HR to call, its about how to go ahead with the situation. Should I encourage her to come to my location and seek for a new job or should I let her stay there and keep trying. She agrees to come back here and search, but with the lack of job opportunities, I am asking her to stay back and keep trying in the hope of getting another call.

Comment: We can't tell you whether you should work from home, whether it's a good idea for your fiancée to quit without a new job or anything else along those lines - that's a purely personal decision you have to sit down together and discuss. What we *can* help with is how to make further contact an employer from whom you'd like a response, and that's what the duplicate question covers.

Comment: @PhilipKendall No problems. I got you. Was not sure how it works. Just thought, if I could find a person with similar experience. I am sure, I won't find any answer for this one now as its already hidden. :) Thanks for the suggestions guys.